# При переименовывании файлов удаляются файлы

Tags: python, bash

Нужно переименовать файлы от 1 и до N. Для этого я написал небольшой скрипт в bash.

Скрипт:

```
i=0;
for name in `ls *.wav`;
do i=$[i+1];
mv $name `printf "%02d" $i`.wav;
done
```

После выполнения скрипта было замечено несоответствие кол-ва файлов в исходной папке с кол-вом переименованных файлов. В попытке решить эту проблему, реализовал этот же скрипт на Python (не нашел, скорее всего удалил). К сожалению, ситуация не изменилась. Файлы, изначально имеющее в своем имени цифры, удалялись.

Долго над решением не думал, поэтому просто взял и добавил в скрипт дополнительный цикл for для того, чтобы сбросить имена, которые содержат цифры, через добавление дополнительного символа в имя файла.

Скрипт на Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# File renamer

# Move the RENAME.py file to the directory with the files you want to rename.
# To run, enter in the terminal: python3 RENAME.py

import os

# constants
FILE_TYPE = '.wav'
LETTER = 'A'
SLASH = '/'
CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()

# index\counter
i = 0
j = 0

initial_list = os.listdir()
initial_list.remove("RENAME.py")
temporary_filenames = []

print("\n\tСurrent directory:\t", CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "\n")

# Rename current files with an extra character added to prevent files from being deleted.
for file in initial_list:
    temporary_filenames.append(file)
    file_location = CURRENT_DIRECTORY + SLASH + temporary_filenames[i]
    temporary_filename = LETTER + str(i) + FILE_TYPE
    i += 1
    os.rename(file_location,temporary_filename)


updated_list = os.listdir()
updated_list.remove("RENAME.py")
persistent_filename = []


for file in updated_list:
    persistent_filename.append(file)
    file_location = CURRENT_DIRECTORY + SLASH + persistent_filename[j]
    j += 1
    new_filename = CURRENT_DIRECTORY + SLASH + str(j) + FILE_TYPE
    print("\tFile:", file_location, "\t\trenamed to:", new_filename)
    os.rename(file_location,new_filename)
    
    
print("\n\tFiles renamed:" + str(j) + "\n")
```

Проблема была решена. Но мне кажется, подобное решения является костыльным.

**Есть ли возможность реализовать подобное без костылей? Заранее спасибо.**

Comment: `man renrot` Что-то типа `renrot -e wav -n '%c'`. http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/renrot/manual/ (Поскольку в WAV файлах есть EXIF теги, то там можно довольно весёлые переименования делать, смотри примеры с картинками)